# Can nonlinear clustering produce 'fake' results?

Tags: clustering, pca, overfitting

I know that overfitting in classification is possible when using, for instance, an RBF kernel, due to its infinite dimension.

But, is it possible to get (in a similar manner) fake clustering results when using this (or other) kernel? i.e., if I run through various kernel widths and get several types of clusters, can one of these be caused by the infinite dimension of the kernel, and not by true clustering of the data? to be specific, let's say I use kernel-PCA with RBF.

I hope my question is clear enough, even though it is not mathematically phrased...
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's better to think of it this way:

Cluster analysis cannot produce "fake results" but random data can cluster, just by chance, and the proportion of times this happens increases as you look at more and more methods and more and more powerful methods.  There are ways to correct for this.

This also happens in the non-mathematical clustering algorithm that happens in our heads - people see patterns in random data.

Comment: Good point. This is part of what I had in mind - can I somehow "scroll" through many/all of the possible "artificial" clustering when I run on just one parameter (in this case - RBF width)? etc. 
Can you please cite methods that explain how to "correct this"?

Comment: Using training, testing and validation data sets.